# Passando variáveis VUE Websockets

Tags: php, vue.js, vue.js-2

Quando eu passo uma variável dessa forma no Vue, como faço para recuperá-la no arquivo PHP?

```
self.ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000?variavel=22');
```

$_GET ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191583/how-to-get-url-param-with-php-websocket#comment65723838_39191583

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, estou tentando aplicar isso sem sucesso, estou fazendo dessa forma:    front: self.ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000?mat_func=22');   back: // Iniciando conexão
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new SimpleChat( @$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
        )
    ),
    9000
);
 
$server->run();    seria algo parecido com isso?

Comment: Evite o uso do `@` no código e se possível utilize o `xDebug` ou `var_dump()` para verificar se as variáveis estão recebendo o valor.